# How to verify a method is only called once, with specific arguments (using RhinoMocks)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I'm just starting to use RhinoMocks. Now I'm wondering what test cases I should write. I want to assert that a method is only being called once, with specific arguments.

Lets start with my interfaces.

```
public class BarQueryParameters
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    void CalFoo(BarQueryParameters parameters);
}

public class FooQueryParameters
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    IEnumerable<string> CallMe(FooQueryParameters parameters);
}
```

Then we have the Bar class that implements `IBar` and calls `IFoo`'s `CallMe` method:

```
public class Bar : IBar
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public void CalFoo(BarQueryParameters parameters)
    {
        List<string> result = _foo.CallMe(new FooQueryParameters
        {
            Id = parameters.Id.ToString(),
            Types = parameters.Categories.ToList()
        }).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
    }
}
```

I want to test that if CallFoo is called with `Id = 1`, `Categories = new List<string> {"One", "Two"}`, this results in a call to `IFoo.CallMe`. I want to make sure the FooQueryParameters are what I expect.

At first I wrote:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFooBarConversion2()
    {
        IFoo mockedFoo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
        mockedFoo.Expect(foo => foo.CallMe(Arg<FooQueryParameters>
            .Matches(p => p.Id.Equals("1") && p.Types.SequenceEqual(new List<string> {"One", "Two"}))))
            .Repeat.Once();

        IBar bar = new Bar(mockedFoo);
        bar.CalFoo(new BarQueryParameters {Id = 1, Categories = new List<string> {"One", "Two"}});

        mockedFoo.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

That won't work as Bar expects a result from its call to Foo.CallMe (it tries to `ToList()` the result). Currently the test will result in a `NullReferenceException`.
So, I'd have to also make sure my mocked method returns something like a `new List<string>()`.

Still not there though. What would happen if `Bar` contains a programming error and calls `CallMe` with incorrect arguments? In that case, the unit test will fail, but not on the `VerifyAllExpectations`. It will again run into a `NullReferenceException`.

So now I'd say my mocked `CallMe` should always return a `new List<string>()`. But I'd still want to make sure it is being called once with the expected arguments. I also want to make sure it is **not** being called with any other arguments.

Then I'd get:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFooBarConversion()
    {
        IFoo mockedFoo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
        mockedFoo.Expect(foo => foo.CallMe(Arg<FooQueryParameters>
            .Matches(p => p.Id.Equals("1") && p.Types.SequenceEqual(new List<string> {"One", "Two"}))))
            .Repeat.Once()
            .Return(new List<string>());
        mockedFoo.Expect(foo => foo.CallMe(Arg<FooQueryParameters>
            .Matches(p => !p.Id.Equals("1") || !p.Types.SequenceEqual(new List<string> {"One", "Two"}))))
            .Repeat.Never()
            .Return(new List<string>());

        IBar bar = new Bar(mockedFoo);
        bar.CalFoo(new BarQueryParameters {Id = 1, Categories = new List<string> {"One", "Two"}});

        mockedFoo.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

This doesn't seem right to me.

1. Is there a simpler way to do this?
2. Should I not care if the method is also called with other arguments?
3. Should I not care if the test fails on a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Might be simpler to turn the second `Expect` into one that just checks it was called at all, exactly once. Combined with the first, that's equivalent to checking that it isn't called with other arguments

Comment: If I do that, the unit test fails on the second expectation. It looks like it considers the single call to CallMe to satisfy both lambda's. But if I change that second one to expect Once, it also fails on the second expectation. (I assume you mean `mockedFoo.Expect(foo => foo.CallMe(Arg<FooQueryParameters>.Is.Anything)).Repeat.Never()`)

Comment: No, I meant what you wrote in that comment, except with `Repeat.Once()` instead of `Repeat.Never()`.

Comment: As I said, when I change it to `Repeat.Never()` it also fails (Expected #1, Actual #0). Wit `Repeat.Once()` it fails with Expected #0, Actual #1. Almost seems like a bug in RhinoMocks?

Comment: Seems weird if that's all you're changing. Unfortunately beyond my level of knowledge of RhinoMocks.

Comment: @comecme I had the same question. The word Repeat is misleading to me. Repeat.Once() means you want the expect or stub to be used once. Repeat.Never() means you never want the expect or stub to be called. Seems like calling it Invoke.Once() or Invoke.Never() would be more logical.